# Generic list: Add, Find, Delete C#

Tags: c#, wpf, list, generics, click

How can I add multiple customers details in a WPF application using a generic list?

Every time a button "Add" is clicked I want to store details entered by the user as a new customer, and then possibly display particular customer by entering only the id number (which was made up by the user when entering details).

I have this class for storing customer details:

```
public class Customer
{
    private int _customerID;
    private string _name;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _customerID; }
        set { _customerID = value; }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
}
```

This is my list:

```
private List<Customer> _list = new List<Customer>();
```

This is the add method:

```
public void add(Customer newCustomer)
        {
            _list.Add(newCustomer);

        }
```

And this is the find method:

```
public Customer find(int id)
        {
            foreach (Customer c in _list)
            {
                if (id == c.ID)
                {
                    return c;

                }
            }

            return null;

        }
```

I am not sure how to implement them in my click event "Add" and "Find"

Please help I am very frustrated with this and there are hardly if any resources according to generic list in WPF.

Comment: Would you please attach the visual part of your application?

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing a new `Customer` and trying to find one with `ID` equals to `0`, as it's the default value. Even if you find one, you're doing nothing with the `customer` returnd by the find method.

You could do something like this:

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Customer customer = store.find(Int32.Parse(txtID.Text));

    ClearCustomerFields();

    if (customer != null)
    {
        FillCustomerFields(customer);
    }
}

private void ClearCustomerFields()
{
    txtID.Text = "";
    txtName.Text = "";
}

private void FillCustomerFields(Customer customer)
{
    txtID.Text = customer.ID.ToString();
    txtName.Text = customer.Name;
}
```

Check out [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/). It's a very powerful tool to interact with enumerable (list-like) types.
Your `find` method could be just this:

```
public Customer find(int id)
{
    return _list.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == id);
}
```